# Route in project is not created, I get a message of "Service with name Domain\v1\SmartLocker\Action\DeliverPackage could not be created. Reason:"

Tags: php, zend-framework, laminas-api-tools, laminas, laminas-http

I created a new route that is called via the POST method in a project where we use Zend Expressive and I went to test it using Insomnia, but the answer the server gives me is the following:

"Service with name Domain\v1\SmartLocker\Action\DeliverPackage could not be created. Reason: "

This is the structure of my folder where my Action and also my Service are:

[image]

This is the getRoutes() method located inside my ConfigProvider.php:

[image]

And this is the error:

[image]

Things I've tried to do but didn't work:

1. Delete data/config-cache.php
2. Change data/config-cache.php permission
3. Change route name and files (I don't know if this makes sense)

Has anyone been through something like this and can you help please?

Comment: Is your config provider being loaded in `config/config.php`? It's weird that the reason is empty.

Comment: Yes, I even defined my ConfigProvider.php file in the ConfigAggregator() array like this: "\Domain\v1\SmartLocker\ConfigProvider::class". I also didn't understand him not showing me the reason why he can't create...

Comment: And have you got your psr-4 autoload setup correctly in `composer.json` and run `composer update`??